# FirstOrDefault In F#

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#

How to write FirstOrDefault Linq Query in F#?
Can I use linq to sql in F# in totally?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note that a more idiomatic approach within F# would probably be to use something along the lines of `Seq.tryFind` rather than to use the LINQ operators, although it's not a drop in replacement since it returns an option value.

Comment: I would also recomend using `Seq.tryFind` - in F#, you generally try to aviod using `null` values (because they are dangerous). Handling option values is easier as you can also use `Option.map` and other functions for working with them (though, this probably won't work in F# LINQ to SQL)

Answer (score 13):

Because the `Seq` module already has a `head` function of type `seq<'a> -> 'a`, I would define a function `tryHead` with signature `seq<'a> -> option<'a>`:

```
module Seq =
    let tryHead (ls:seq<'a>) : option<'a>  = ls |> Seq.tryPick Some
```

using it as:

```
[1; 2; 3] |> Seq.tryHead
```

Comment: Since then `tryHead` (https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/commit/b10392dc16593bf9286583e2a87217d18fa18b8a) has been added in F# 4.0.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding LINQ-to-SQL, see

http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2009/10/23/a-quick-refresh-on-query-support-in-the-f-power-pack.aspx

Regarding `FirstOrDefault`, it's just an extension [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) in the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
let l = [1;2;3]
open System.Linq 
let r = l.FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can define your own firstordefault easily:

```
let firstordefault list =
   match list with
   | head :: tail -> head 
   | [] -> 0 // some default value
```

Example:

```
let exampleList = [ 1; 2; 3 ]
```

using F# interactive,

```
firstordefault exampleList;;  
val it : int = 1
```