# SingleOrDefault in F#

Tags: linq, f#, c#-to-f#

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784281/firstordefault-in-f) question - what is the most idiomatic way to write LINQ's [SingleOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault) in F#?

Comment: `seq` is an `IEnumerable<>` which means you can use LINQ operators in F# just like C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the function to return `null` (or default for value types) when the sequence is empty, just go ahead and call the existing `SingleOrDefault` method. You can call C# methods from F# just fine. Keep in mind, however, that most F# native types do not admit nulls, so this may not always be possible.

If you want your function to return an option type, falling back to `None` when the sequence contains zero elements or more than one, you can use `Seq.truncate` to truncate to the first two elements:

```
let singleOrDefault s =
    match s |> Seq.truncate 2 |> Seq.toList with
    | [x] -> Some x
    | _ -> None
```

Or similarly for the overload that also takes a predicate:

```
let singleOrDefaultP pred s =
    match s |> Seq.filter pred |> Seq.truncate 2 |> Seq.toList with
    | [x] -> Some x
    | _ -> None
```

If you prefer having both versions around, it probably makes sense to express one in terms of the other to keep things DRY:

```
let singleOrDefault s = singleOrDefaultP (fun _ -> true) s
```

The advantage of this solution over using an additional `Seq.isEmpty` check is that the sequence is only evaluated once, and only as far as it needs to.

Incidentally, this is exactly what [the default implementation of `SingleOrDefault`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Single.cs#L102) does.

Also note that this solution will return `None` when the sequence contains more than one element, instead of throwing an exception, as the original does. This is preferred, idiomatic way of dealing with errors in F#. However, if you prefer the original way, it can be easily achieved by adding another case to the match:

```
let singleOrDefault s =
    match s |> Seq.truncate 2 |> Seq.toList with
    | [x] -> Some x
    | [_;_] -> failWith "Too many"  // replace with your favourite exception
    | _ -> None
```

Comment: Single works with a predicate. The equivalnet in F# would be  `Seq.filter predicate |> Seq.exactlyOne` as shown in this [almost duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850769/f-equivalent-of-linq-single). The *idiomatic* SingleOrDefault would have to return None if nothing was found

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos (1) you caught the unfinished answer, still being iterated on; I have already added the predicate version; (2) there are two overloads of `SingleOrDefault` - one with predicate, one without; (3) The "equivalent in F#" that you provided will throw an exception instead of returning `None` or default.

Comment: The annnoying thing is that the duplicate is good enough already for *Single*. A better answer would have to return `None` *without* multiple iterations, which means `isEmpty` can't be used.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the accepted answer in the "duplicate" question iterates over the sequence twice - once for `Seq.length` and once for `Seq.head`.

Comment: Errmmm, SingleOrDefault *throws* if there are more than 1 matches. `truncate` isn't a good option

Comment: The *updates* don't, they use `Seq.filter predicate |> Seq.exactlyOnce`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The non-throwing behaviour is by design. I added a note about that.

Comment: Oh for... [Seq.exactlyOnce](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1412) is cheating! Might as well rewrite it into a `tryExactlyOnce that returns an option!

Answer (score 4):

If you need the exact behaviour of `SingleOrDefault`, I suggest the following:

```
module Seq

open System.Linq

let singleOrDefault (s : 'x seq) =
    s.SingleOrDefault ()
```

Otherwise, see your own answer for a perfectly sensible solution.

Answer (score 1):

My take is to have some `SequenceExtensions.fs` with

```fs
module Seq 

let trySingle = function
    | seq when seq |> Seq.isEmpty ->
        None
    | seq ->
        seq
        |> Seq.exactlyOne
        |> Some
```

To be used elsewhere like `[42] |> Seq.trySingle`.

Comment: I believe you can more compactly write this as follows: ``let trySingle s = if Seq.isEmpty s then None else Some (Seq.exactlyOne s)``

Comment: That's not the same as Single or SingleOrDefault. Single returns the single item that matches its predicate